# How to show warning for the code reformat shortcut in Android Studio/Intellij

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

This shortcut [Reformat in Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html) is being used excessively in a team I'm working the makes it impossible during code review to distinguish the real logic change from just code reformat.

What I would like to achieve is show a custom warning dialog to confirm the change.

Comment: Do you need separate highliting for lines changed while logic changed and while code reformat?

Comment: Actually what I have in mind is to show a confirmation dialog before this action takes place to warn the developer that this action will cause many line changes, so the developer has the option to either proceed or cancel

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Currently it's not possible. Feel free to create feature request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA